# How to handle rounding errors in Java's BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm working with open source project (axil) that implements a scripting engine inside of java applications and I've hit a major stumbling block while trying to utilize BigDecimal's rounding.  It seems that BigDecimal is converting my input to scientific notation and then applying my passed in precision to the coefficient of the SN representation of the number, rather than to its non-SN representation.  For example:

`new BigDecimal("-232454.5324").round(new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)).toString()`

produces a result of `-2.3E+5`.  This presents two problems for me.  First, I am expecting a result of `-232454.5` (`-2.324545E+5`), so getting `-230000` throws off any math that involves the result.  And second, I am not expecting, nor can I find a way around, getting the results in SN (though I expect there is a formatting method out there that I haven't yet stumbled across).

Now due to the nature of the project, we can make very few expectations about what size/type of numbers will be getting passed into the round() method, so any solution needs to be highly modular.  Does anyone have any suggestions? [If it would be helpful here's a link to the google code issue report for this bug in the project.](http://code.google.com/p/axil/issues/detail?id=58)  [And here is a link to the project homepage.](http://www.axil-lang.org/)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use the round method , use setScale instead, where argument is number of decimals:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("-232454.5324").setScale(1,
                RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
String string = bd.toPlainString();
System.out.println(string); // prints -232454.5
```

Also note that setScale returns a new BigDecimal instance, it doesn't change the scale of the current instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't solve the problem for other rounding modes.  For instance:

`new BigDecimal("23.2222").setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString()` 

Produces 23, when a half-even rounding rules dictate that it should result in 24 (the nearest even integer).  How do I apply rounding rules to a scaling operation?

Comment: @JoeliusCaeser, Well, System.out.println(new BigDecimal("23.5").setScale(0,RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString()); 
prints 24. 
But wouldn't 23.222 always be rounded down to 23 when no decimals are requested, regardless of rounding mode??

Comment: Nope, rounding to 23 is correct in this case.  HALF_EVEN specifies that you round to the even integer _only_ when the fractional part is _exactly_ 0.5, and otherwise round to the _nearest_ integer.

Comment: Oh goodness you're right.  That's my bad, thanks so much for the help guys!

Comment: This old [not-an-issue](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4508009) page regarding the JDK has given me useful informations when searching for rounding errors, so I thought I'd link it here.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like that:

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("22.2222").setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP);

if (number.intValue() % 2 != 0) {
    number = number.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
}

System.out.println(number); // => 24
```

Answer (score 1):

A `MathContext` takes a *precision*, which is the *total* number of significant digits -- before and after the decimal place -- in the result.  `BigDecimal`'s logic is correct here.