# java BigDecimal round up/down automatically

Tags: java, rounding

i have a function that calculates data that creates a BigDecimal format variable and im trying to round up or down accordingly with the results. For instance:

16.543242123 should be 16.5
3.35 should be 3.4
6.3456 should be 6.3

and so on, if the 3rd digit is equal to 5 or above to round up the 2nd digit, if its equal to 4 and below, to remove the 3rd digit. This does not absolutely need to be BigDecimal, i can figure out converting the numbers after i manage to do the rounds up.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883308/how-to-handle-rounding-errors-in-javas-bigdecimal/10883502#10883502

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
  BigDecimal bg1 = new BigDecimal(16.543242123);
  bg1 = bg1.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
  System.out.println(bg1.toString());  //16.5

  BigDecimal bg2 = new BigDecimal(3.35);
  bg2 = bg2.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
  System.out.println(bg2.toString()); //3.4

  BigDecimal bg3 = new BigDecimal(6.3456);
  bg3 = bg3.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN);
  System.out.println(bg3.toString());  //6.3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("16.553242123");
BigDecimal format = bd.setScale(1, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```